Retraining YOLOv9 on some of COCO Subclasses and Applying Transfer Learning to a Custom Dataset which contain new class not exist in coco
I am embarking on a project utilizing YOLOv9, initially trained on the COCO dataset's 80 classes. My focus is on vehicle detection, specifically targeting four classes: cars, motorcycles, buses, and trucks. I intend to modify the YOLO architecture and the COCO dataset settings to include only these four classes, rather than filtering them out in the Python code. I plan to adjust the coco.yaml file to redefine class IDs as follows:
0: car
1: motorcycle
2: bus
3: truck
Could altering the class IDs in this way impact the pre-existing training on the COCO dataset? If this change necessitates retraining, could you guide me through the necessary steps?
Additionally, after adapting YOLOv9 to detect only these four vehicle classes, I aim to incorporate a new class, "van," from a custom dataset I've prepared. This dataset includes the original four classes plus the new "van" class. I wish to retrain YOLOv9 on this new dataset without losing the pretrained COCO weights.
Could you provide detailed steps on how to:
Adjust the model and dataset settings for targeted retraining on the four specific classes?
Integrate and train on the new class while retaining the effectiveness of the COCO-pretrained weights?
I am quite new to this field and find some of these concepts confusing. Clear, step-by-step guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance for your assistance.
changed coco .yaml to :
0: car
1: motorcycle
2: bus
3: truck

changed nc variable to 4 in necessary files

prepared my custom dataset that contains the 4 classes + new class

I see you tagged your question with roboflow tag, so I think it's worth to point out you can achieve what you are asking through Roboflow platform.
If you go to Roboflow app and create an account there (there is free trial you can sign up for), you can create a workspace there. When creating workspace you can select project type (i.e. object detection, classification, instance segmentation or keypoint detection). If you select object detection you will be given option to specify classes of objects (i.e. I have done a chess board detection project there and I wanted to detect classes like white pawn, black pawn etc.). You'll then upload your photos and annotate them and train your model - you are given multiple options to select base models. As a result I got a model which when executed inference on it I got only classes I specified on my dataset.
Hope this helps!
